# Adding JQuery Plugin to Angular 2 Component

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to add a snippet of jQuery code to a component that I got online. [Specifically this.](https://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/)

I already have the HTML and the CSS implemented into the code but I am having troubles getting the jQuery to load at all. I used `<script>` tags at the bottom of the html part but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using material by any chance you could replicate that with the tabs and would all be angular. Are you just using jquery just for this plugin or also for other things within your app?

Comment: @JJB I am just using it for one thing in my app right now.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Are you using SystemJS or Webpack?

Comment: If your goal is simply to add a slider, there is a simple slider in Bootstrap 4 you can use that doesn't require any plugins. There are also some free Angular 2 sliders that don't use jQuery. While it is possible to use jQuery with Angular 2, jQuery does not play well with it. I recommend considering non-jQuery alternatives if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewChild decorator to get the reference of HTML content and then use that reference in you component inside `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook.You can use the reference any where inside your component but if want to do any kind of initialisation using jQuery then `ngAfterViewInit` is a suitable place to do that.

for example if the HTML template have following code.

```
<!-- my-component.html-->

<section class="cd-hero">
    <ul class="cd-hero-slider">
        <li class="selected">
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2><!-- title here  --></h2>
                <p><!-- description here --></p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn"><!-- btn text here --></a>
            </div> <!-- .cd-full-width -->
        </li>

        <!-- othe slides here -->

    </ul> <!-- .cd-hero-slider -->

    <div class="cd-slider-nav" #cdSliderNav >
        <nav>
            <span class="cd-marker item-1"></span>

            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="#0">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Tech 1</a></li>
                <!-- other navigation items here -->
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </div> <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
</section> <!-- .cd-hero -->
```

then I can get the reference of `cdSliderNav` variable in my component as follows.

```
//myComponent.ts

declare var jQuery: any

@Component({
  selector:'my-component',
  templateUrl:'my-component.html',
  styleUrls:['my-component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('cdSliderNav') cdSliderNav:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      jQuery(this.cdSliderNav.nativeElement).on('click',
       event => {
                   //Handle click event here..
                  console.log(event);
                }
      )
  }
}
```

you can also declare jQuery variable inside your typings file if you don't want to declare it separately for each component file.And make sure that you have included jQuery file inside your `index.html` file.

Once we got the reference to the main div then we can use jQuery methods to select its child or do whatever we want using jQuery. for ex. to select `li` elements inside my `cdSliderNav` i can use the `find()` method.

```
jQuery(this.cdSliderNav.nativeElement).find('li')
```

i hope this will help.